# iTunes only plays first part of song

Tags: macos, itunes, music, m4a

I downloaded an album from iTunes Store on my MacBook (macOS 10.13.6).

One of the songs, only the first 17 seconds play. Then it jumps to the next song.

The total time of the song is displayed correctly (4:06).

When I navigate to ~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Music and find the album, the m4a file that the song is stored in does the same thing:

QuickTime shows it's 4:06 long, but only plays the first 17 seconds then freezes. Trying to skip with the scrubber past 0:17 in QuickTime causes the song to be unplayable, unless I put it back before 0:17.

How can I fix this? I want iTunes to play the whole song.

Comment: The file is corrupted. Delete and re-download.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a different player like VLC and check whether that works.

But it's way more likely that the file is just corrupted. You can try to copy it again from the source.

Comment: What's the easiest way for me to re-download?

Comment: That depends on where you have gotten the file.

Comment: "I downloaded an album from iTunes Store"

Comment: You can delete the song from your hard drive and then redownload it from iTunes like this: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201272